# Filter users with many roles Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, filter

I have 3 tables: User, Role and the pivot table RoleUser with role_id and user_id.

For the relations in my models i did that :

Role Model :

```
   public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->using(RoleUser::class);
}
```

User Model:

```
 public function roles() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Role')->using(RoleUser::class);
}
```

I did that for filter by one role and it works well :

```
 $roles = Role::find($request->get('role_id'))->first();

 return $roles->users;
```

But now i need to filter my users by many roles.

I ll send an array from my front-end with id's of the roles.

Actually i'm able to get the roles like below

```
$roles = Role::whereIn('id', $request->get('role_id'))->get();


 $roles = [{"id":2,"name":"Admin","description":"blabla","created_at":"2018-12-04 09:48:56","updated_at":"2021-04-23 14:53:15"},{"id":3,"name":"developper","description":"blabla","created_at":"2018-12-04 09:51:31","updated_at":"2021-04-23 14:53:15"}]
```

But i dont know how can i get the users with this roles.

Comment: Please note that a `many-to-many`, using the `belongsToMany()` method, should use that method for both models `User` and `Role`. You currently have `hasMany()` on the `User` model, but that should be `belongsToMany()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through the collection and get each role's users and return them in one array as shown below:

```
$roles = Role::whereIn('id', $request->get('role_id'))->get();
return $roles->map->users->flatten();
```

Or you do it the other way round:

```
return User::whereHas('roles', function($q) use($request) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $request->get('role_id'));
})->get();
```

Comment: the first method works but the problem is map create a new array so when i fetch my data i get a double array [[data]].. how can i manage for having a simple array ? The second method not working tell me "undefined variable request"

Comment: I fixed the second method. Yeah, the first method results in a nested array. That's why I `flatten()` it.

Comment: with flatten i get this error "Property [flatten] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: Oh, I forgot the parentheses since `flatten()` is not a higher order messages.